Query to Count Records in a 1-Hour Sliding Window
I have a table where each record represents a transaction by a user. I need to find out if any user has inserted 1000 or more records within a 1 hour time window on a specific date. For example, if a user inserts more than 1000 records between 12:15 PM to 01:15 PM, I want to capture that information.



user_code
timestamp




John
2024-12-01 01:17:05


John
2024-12-01 01:17:35


John
2024-12-01 01:18:05


John
2024-12-01 01:18:35


John
2024-12-01 01:19:05


John
2024-12-01 01:19:35


John
2024-12-01 01:20:05


Alex
2024-12-01 01:30:15


Alex
2024-12-01 01:30:45


Alex
2024-12-01 01:31:15


Alex
2024-12-01 01:31:45


Alex
2024-12-01 01:32:15


Alex
2024-12-01 01:32:45


Alex
2024-12-01 01:33:15



What I've Tried:
I've tried following a basic approach with the help of ChatGPT, but the query generated, even by AI, is not working as expected. The sliding window calculation seems to be incorrect in its handling, and I’m not able to capture the data as intended.
Approach:

For each user, calculate a sliding window (1 hour before and 1 hour
after each transaction).
Count the number of records within each window.
Return only the windows where the count of records is 1000 or more.

I am looking for help to write the correct Oracle SQL query to implement the above logic. If anyone has any suggestions, or a correct query to achieve this, it would be greatly appreciated!

An arbitrary 1-hour sliding window is unbounded with an infinite number of start/end points.  Which windows do you actually want to check?

You're absolutely right. We're designing a system where users can perform bulk insertions, and we'd like to charge them based on that activity. For example, if a user inserts up to 10,000 records within an hour, the charge will be fixed for that period. Once that hour ends, we'll charge them again for the next hour, regardless of whether they insert more records or not.

Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for your sample data; YOUR attempt at a solution; the issues/errors with YOUR solution; and the expected output for your sample data. Your current sample data does not have 1000 rows and you have not told us what the format of the expected output is.

The rule is not quite clear.  Suppose John inserted 6,000 records 01:15 to 02:00 ; 7,000 02:00 to 02:15 ; 8'000  02:15 to 03:15. What is the expected result?

Use an analytic function with a range window:
SELECT user_code,
       timestamp
FROM   (
  SELECT user_code,
         timestamp,
         COUNT(*) OVER (
           PARTITION BY user_code
           ORDER BY timestamp
           RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '0' HOUR PRECEDING
                     AND INTERVAL '1' HOUR FOLLOWING
         ) AS cnt
  FROM   table_name
)
WHERE  cnt >= 1000

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (user_code, timestamp) AS
SELECT 'Alice',
        TIMESTAMP '2024-01-01 00:00:00' + INTERVAL '3' SECOND * (LEVEL - 1)
FROM    DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1003
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Beryl',
        TIMESTAMP '2024-01-01 00:00:00' + INTERVAL '3' SECOND * (LEVEL - 1)
FROM    DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 500
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Beryl',
        TIMESTAMP '2024-01-01 00:00:00' + INTERVAL '3' SECOND * (LEVEL + 501)
FROM    DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 500
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Carol',
        TIMESTAMP '2024-01-01 00:00:00' + INTERVAL '3' SECOND * (LEVEL - 1)
FROM    DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 900


Outputs the start of the hour ranges which contain 1000 or more rows:



USER_CODE
TIMESTAMP




Alice
2024-01-01 00:00:00.000000000


Alice
2024-01-01 00:00:03.000000000


Alice
2024-01-01 00:00:06.000000000


Alice
2024-01-01 00:00:09.000000000


Beryl
2024-01-01 00:00:00.000000000




If you want to return the 1-hour ranges then, from Oracle 12, you can use MATCH_RECOGNIZE:
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
       MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
         PARTITION BY user_code
         ORDER BY timestamp
         MEASURES
           FIRST(timestamp) AS timestamp_start,
           LAST(timestamp)  AS timestamp_end,
           COUNT(timestamp) AS cnt
         PATTERN (start_row within_1_hour+)
         DEFINE
           within_1_hour AS timestamp <= FIRST(timestamp) + INTERVAL '1' HOUR
       )
WHERE  cnt >= 1000

Which, for the sample data, outputs:



USER_CODE
TIMESTAMP_START
TIMESTAMP_END
CNT




Alice
2024-01-01 00:00:00.000000000
2024-01-01 00:50:06.000000000
1003


Beryl
2024-01-01 00:00:00.000000000
2024-01-01 00:50:03.000000000
1000



fiddle

Thanks for your effort! However, the result I'm getting is incorrect. It should return only 2 records with the maximum count because all of John's inserted records fall within a 1-hour span. Currently, I’m getting multiple rows with incrementing values. For example, John will have 5 records ranging from 1000 to 1005, but it should be just one record with the start and end date for that time frame.

@Karim You have not told us what the expected output is; if you don't fully explain the problem then how can we know what a "correct" solution looks like.

Your solution with "MATCH_RECOGNIZE" worked as expected! Thanks a lot

Maybe this could help you:
--    S a m p l e    D a t a : 
CREATE TABLE tbl (user_code, timestamp) AS
SELECT 'Alice', TIMESTAMP '2024-01-01 00:00:00' + INTERVAL '20' MINUTE * (LEVEL - 1)
FROM    DUAL  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 9
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Beryl', TIMESTAMP '2024-01-01 00:00:00' + INTERVAL '20' MINUTE * (LEVEL - 1)
FROM    DUAL  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Beryl', TIMESTAMP '2024-01-01 00:00:00' + INTERVAL '20' MINUTE * (LEVEL + 1)
FROM    DUAL  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Carol', TIMESTAMP '2024-01-01 00:00:00' + INTERVAL '20' MINUTE * (LEVEL - 1)
FROM    DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2


I need to find out if any user has inserted 1000 or more records within a 1 hour time window on a specific date

Create a CTE (grid) to get a date and timeframes of 1 hour before and 1 hour after the current row. Then count previous and following rows per user and date ...
WITH
  grid AS 
    ( SELECT   user_code, timestamp, a_date, prev_hour, next_hour,
               Count(*) Over(Partition By user_code, a_date 
                             Order By timestamp
                             Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) as cnt_prev, 
               Count(*) Over(Partition By user_code, a_date
                             Order By timestamp
                             Rows Between Current Row And Unbounded Following) as cnt_next 
      FROM   ( Select   user_code, timestamp, Trunc(timestamp) as a_date,
                        timestamp - INTERVAL '1' HOUR as prev_hour,
                        timestamp + INTERVAL '1' HOUR as next_hour
               From     tbl
             )
      WHERE  timestamp Between prev_hour And timestamp 
           OR
             timestamp Between timestamp And next_hour
    )

... now get Max counts bigger than some value (here it is 8 - you put 1000) and group by columns that you want to (here it is user_code, a_date and a_time - that could be just the user_code if you want)
--      M a i n    S Q L :
Select   user_code, a_date, To_Char(timestamp, 'hh24:mi:ss') as a_time, Max(cnt_prev) as cnt_prev, Max(cnt_next) as cnt_next
From     grid
Group By user_code, a_date, To_Char(timestamp, 'hh24:mi:ss')
HAVING   Max(cnt_prev) > 8 OR Max(cnt_next) > 8
Order By user_code, a_date, To_Char(timestamp, 'hh24:mi:ss')

R e s u l t :



USER_CODE
A_DATE
A_TIME
CNT_PREV
CNT_NEXT




Alice
01-JAN-24
00:00:00
1
9


Alice
01-JAN-24
02:40:00
9
1



fiddle
